# Windows Live movie maker hangs

Tags: windows-7, video-editing, windows-live-movie-maker

I have installed windows live movie maker 2011 on windows 7 64 bit machine. I can make clips using photos but as soon as I add music to it movie maker hangs and stops responding. I uninstalled and re-installed it  but no success same issue.
Can anyone tell me what can be the issue? or any alternative to movie maker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pramodtech, have you tried updating your video and audio drivers? Go to device manager, right click on the video and audio driver, and click "Update device software".

Answer (score 0):

It may be hanging because of some sound driver problem. Check the event log at `eventvwr.exe`, for the error code, and you can check it at MSDN.

Adobe Premiere pro is the best for professional video editing.http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html

Comment: Thanks anirudh. I did check event log & msg says "The program MovieMaker.exe version 15.4.3508.1109 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel." But I don't see any detail in Action centre.

Comment: Does it happen ONLY when you add mp3s? When does it happen?

Comment: it happens with audio and video files. I can apply visual effects to photos but no audio effects.

Comment: Try changing the filter options from Tools / Options / Compatibility tab.